# How to delete file in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have create some coding for delete temporary table that i have created. Following are the coding.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($What_services_post); $i++) {
     $sql = "SELECT `provider_id` FROM `provider_service_need` WHERE `service_need`='".$What_services_post[$i]."'";
     $stmt = $dbg->query($sql);
     foreach ($stmt as $row_service_need) {
         $p_id = $row_service_need['provider_id'];
         if ($result_looking_for) {   
             $sql = "SELECT `p_id` FROM `temprari_provider_filter_looking_for` WHERE `p_id`='$p_id' AND `f_id`='$finder_id' GROUP BY `p_id`";
             $stmt = $dbg->query($sql);
             $row_looking_temp2 = $stmt->fetch();
             if ($row_looking_temp2['p_id'] == $p_id) {
                 $result_filter_servic = $dbg->exec("INSERT INTO `temprari_provider_filter_service_need`(`p_id`, `f_id`) VALUES ('$p_id','$finder_id')") or die("Insert Failed ".mysql_error());

                 $count = $dbg->prepare("DELETE FROM `temprari_provider_filter_looking_for` WHERE `p_id`='$p_id' AND `f_id`='$finder_id'")or die("Delets Failed ".mysql_error());
                 $count->execute();
             } else {
                 $result_filter_servic=$dbg->exec("INSERT INTO `temprari_provider_filter_service_need`(`p_id`, `f_id`) VALUES ('$p_id','$finder_id')") or die("Insert Failed ".mysql_error());

                  $count=$dbg->prepare("DELETE FROM `temprari_provider_filter_looking_for` WHERE `p_id`='$p_id' AND `f_id`='$finder_id'")or die("Delets Failed ".mysql_error());
                  $count->execute();
             }
         } else {
            $result_filter_servic=$dbg->exec("INSERT INTO `temprari_provider_filter_service_need`(`p_id`, `f_id`) VALUES ('$p_id','$finder_id')") or die("Insert Failed ".mysql_error());
         }
    }
}
```

I want delete all the data where `p_id` AND `f_id` are. But it's not working. And i can't find the false. Please can some one help me.

Comment: Firstly, PDO + `mysql_` do **NOT** intermix. Use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Plus, how do we know if you're also not using `mysql_` to connect with?

Comment: Eeek. So many things wrong with this code. Don't know where to start.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to throw away that code and start again. But this time, follow some decent examples, like those at [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension).